# Word for the feeling of perfectly describing a concept?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for the feeling (possibly of satisfaction) caused by describing a concept or idea with perfect clarity?

Comment: perhaps "feeling eloquent" ... but you'd need both the word "feeling" along with "eloquent"

Comment: "nailing it"--informally.

Comment: The description fits it "to a T".

Comment: This is primarily opinion-based because it depends on the psychology of the person who did the describing. For example, someone forced to describe something with perfect clarity due to blackmail might feel frustration upon doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Technically **'Afterglow'** fits well with your question, although it would be nice to know the context it would used in as it may not be the most appropriate.

Afterglow (Noun) - a pleasant feeling produced after an experience, event, feeling, etc.:

'Bast was basking in the afterglow of describing his concept perfectly.'